# Comerla not found in conjugation tables

Tags: tiempos-verbales, enclisis

I can't find `comerla` in the conjugation tables. Can a sympathetic person please shed some light on this for me? What's going on?

I found these sentences on 123teachme:

> Por favor, póngame una piña 'durita', pues no voy a comerla inmediatamente.
> Please, give me an unripe pineapple, since I'm not going to eat it soon.
>
> Yo odiaba tanto la coliflor que me negaba a comerla.
> I used to hate cauliflower so much that I refused to eat it.
>
> Enrique viene a comer pizza al restaurante. Enrique viene a comerla al restaurante.
> Enrique comes to eat pizza at the restaurant. Enrique comes to eat it at the restaurant.
>
> Enrique viene a comer pizza al restaurante. Enrique viene a comerla al restaurante.
> Enrique comes to eat pizza in the restaurant. Enrique comes to eat it in the restaurant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The conjugation is just `comer`, but it has attached the pronoun that identifies the direct object.

These two sentneces have the same meaning.

> Por favor, póngame una piña 'durita', pues no voy a comer**la** inmediatamente.
>
> Por favor, póngame una piña 'durita', pues no **la** voy a comer inmediatamente.

Some of the pronouns can go immediately in front of the verb or immediately after.

You could check section 3 of [this link](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=elLl31yYnD65MTS9uF) (in Spanish) to learn more about it.

Comment: I'm still slightly confused. El and la are definite articles, not pronouns. It seems though that la and el in these cases can also serve as pronouns for 'it'. Correct?

Comment: "El" is an article. "La" can either be an article or a pronoun. For "it" you would use "lo". A quick search showed me [this link about pronouns in Spanish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_pronouns), which you may find useful. Also, here is a link to the RAE about [the usage of certain pronouns](http://www.rae.es/consultas/uso-de-los-pronombres-los-las-les-leismo-laismo-loismo)

Answer (score 3):

I use words like "comerla" all the time, but I never questioned why they are constructed like that. Seeing this quesition made me wander about that and I did a little reaserch. The topic can be quite complex, but the simple explanation is this:

Words like comerla, correrlo, mancharse, contarnos, llegarme, are verbs accompanied by unstressed personal pronouns. The verbs in the examples are: comer, correr, tener, contar, llegar. And the pronouns are: la, lo, se, nos, me.

In this case, the unstressed personal pronoun is called "clítico" (no translation available), and when the pronoun is before the verb (la como, lo corrí) they are calles also pronoun "proclítico", and when they are attached to the end of the verb, then they are called pronoun "enclítico".

So, this is the translation for the exam´le I gave at the begining of this text:

Comerla = Eat it, la is for female gender so it refers to a thing or a person which is female.

Correrlo = Can be understood like "fire him" as in a job or to "play it" as in a movie, even can be understood like "run it" as in a software.

Mancharse = stain him, her, it

Contarnos= Tell us

Llegarme = reach me, (va a llegarme un pedido can be translated as: I will get an order

Hope this help somebody.

The link where I read some info about the subject: http://fernando.liroz.es/s/clit.htm

Comment: clítico is simply clitic in English.  Likewise, enclítico is enclitic, proclítico is proclitic, mesoclítico is mesoclitic and endoclítico is endoclitic.

Comment: There is a well known example of a clitic in English: the saxon genitive (`'s`).

Answer (score 0):

**verb + lo(la)** applies to: comerlo, saltarlo, bailarlo, alejarlo, pensarlo, quebrarlo, etc.

The complex stuff is to put it in spanish, because in english we say **eat it** and that's it, there's no difference between genres. However, the only way to differentiate this by identifying the noun.

We know it's "la piña" and not "el piña," so for the verb "eat" it follows that is "comerla" and not "comerlo."

The hardest thing is to learn which "la" or "lo" attaches to the noun, once known this, it's not hard anymore.